# How to Convert Date Time using Offset values

Tags: c#, date, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I Need to convert a DateTime accordign to the given offset value. 
I have values like:

-08:00

-07:00

+08:00

+07:00

+02:00

+05:30

How I can convert a date time according to these given offset values. 
I tried:

```
string t = "Pacific Standard Time";
var tInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(t);
var data = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, tInfo);
```

this is fine to but I need to convert based on offset value.

Plz suggest here how to convert it.

Thanks

Comment: what do you get as input and what do you expect as output, do you only get the offset value?

Comment: BTW everyone except Windows (that means airlines, web sites etc) uses the IANA timezone names, not the non-standard three-letter codes or descriptive names.

Answer (score 3):

The type that stores timezone offsets is [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.7.2). If you care about offsets use that type instead of DateTime. Otherwise you won't be able to compare dates with different offsets unless you also store the offset along with the datetime.

Properties like [DateTimeOffset.Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.now?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [DateTimeOffset.UtcNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.utcnow?view=netframework-4.7.2) will return the current time in the machine's timezone or UTC respectively.

Creating a DateTimeOffset from a DateTime in a specific offset is as simple as calling the appropriate constructor, eg :

```
var pstTime=new DateTimeOffset(2019,1,14,1,0,0,new TimeSpan(-8,0,0));
```

You can convert a `DateTimeOffset` value to different offsets with [ToOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tooffset?view=netframework-4.7.2), eg :

```
var eastEuropeTime=pstTime.ToOffset(new TimeSpan(2,0,0));
```

This will return 11am.

[ToUniversalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.touniversaltime?view=netframework-4.7.2) will return the time in UTC, ie +00:00:

```
var utcTime=pstTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

Which returns 9 am.

**Conversion from/to DateTime**

You can also construct a DateTimeOffset from an existing `DateTime` value. The [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTimeOffset__ctor_System_DateTime_System_TimeSpan_) check the input DateTime's [Kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=netframework-4.7.2) property and refuses to use invalid offsets if `DateTime.Kind`.

For Utc the only valid value is 00:00.

```
var now=DateTime.UtcNow;
var utcOffset=new DateTimeOffset(now, TimeSpan.Zero);
utcOffset.Dump();
```

For a local time, the only valid value is the machine's offset. To convert a local time to DateTimeOffset, you can retrieve its offset from  `TimeZoneInfo.Local` :

```
var now=DateTime.Now;
var localOffset=new DateTimeOffset(now, TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(now));
```

**Arbitrary Offsets**

In some cases we may want to use a DateTime as is with a *specific* offset. Many web sites (especially forums) for example allow users to specify their timezone and thus avoid problems with timezone detection on the browser.

In other cases, the offset may be stored separately or come from an IANA timezone name.

To use an arbitrary offset, the DateTime's Kind must have the `Unspecified`:

```
var date=new DateTime(2019,01,15,18.17.00, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var pst=new DateTimeOffset(date,new TimeSpan(-8,0,0));
```

This is useful eg when loading `datetime` values from a database. DateTime values loaded from a database are `Unspecified`.

Values that come from code or input controls may already be Local or UTC. In this case we need to use [DateTime.SpecifyKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.specifykind?view=netframework-4.7.2) to create a new `Unspecified` DateTime value :

```
var date=DateTime.SpecifyKind(domeDate,DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var pst=new DateTimeOffset(date,new TimeSpan(-8,0,0));
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go, +1

Comment: The code you showed with `DateTime.Now` and `SpecifyKind` is not so great, in that it gives a time value that matches the local time zone with potentially some other offset associated.  The resulting dto might not be "now" at all.   If you want "now at a specific offset from UTC", then I would instead recommend using `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(theTimespanRepresentingTheOffset)`.  Cheers. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson the point of the answer is to show that the correct type is DateTimeOffset and how to use each constructor. The question itself doesn't explain what the OP actually wants. The value could be user input from a web application or a database. Hmm, a datepicker example would be better than `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is [DateTimeOffset.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

For example:

```
var offsetValue = "+08:00";
var now = DateTime.Now;
var nowString = now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
var offsetDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse($"{nowString} {offsetValue}");
```

Please note the above is just an example, this is ignoring any sort of culture specific issues etc.

Comment: Why go through a string and parsing instead of the concstructor?

Comment: I was writing it off the top of my head, couldn't remember every constructor it used. This is to answer the question, I did make note it was an example, and a rough one at that. It explains the class he can use to achieve his goal.